# R: Webscrape article

Tags: r

I want to web scrape the following article (Greek language)

https://www.capital.gr/politiki/3460863/x-theoxaris-i-krisi-mporei-na-apotelesei-eukairia-gia-ton-elliniko-tourismo

I am not sure how to do it. I tried rvest but was unsuccessful:

```
url <- 'https://www.capital.gr/politiki/3460863/x-theoxaris-i-krisi-mporei-na-apotelesei-eukairia-gia-ton-elliniko-tourismo'

read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(css = ".wcms-article-content") %>%
  html_text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
url <- 'https://www.capital.gr/politiki/3460863/x-theoxaris-i-krisi-mporei-na-apotelesei-eukairia-gia-ton-elliniko-tourismo'

library(rvest)
read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(css = "#articleBody p") %>%
  html_text

[1] "\n\tΜία \"ανάσα\" πριν την έναρξη της τουριστικής σεζόν, ο υπουργός Τουρισμού Χάρης Θεοχάρης παρουσίασε από τη Σαντορίνη το πρόγραμμα \"Τουρισμός για όλους\", ένα πρόγραμμα για τη στήριξη της εσωτερικής τουριστικής κίνησης, των επιχειρήσεων και της απασχόλησης.\n"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 [2] "\n\t\"Αυτές οι ημέρες etc. etc...
```

Comment: thanks a lot! May I ask you how did you find that css = "#articleBody p"?

Comment: You're welcome! Sure, one of the easiest ways is via the chrome browser extension called "css selector gadget"